# trying to return an array already populated but it returns an empty table

Tags: angularjs, factory

```
.controller("TasksCtrl", function ($scope, tasksFactory) {

            $scope.tasks = tasks;

            $scope.addNew = function(task){
              alert("Add new called!");
              $scope.tasks.push(task);
            };

            $scope.remove = function(index){

              $scope.tasks.splice(index, 1);
            };
            $scope.edit= function(task){
              $scope.current = task;
            };
            $scope.save= function(task){
              $scope.current = {};
            };

        })
```

So I don't know if the mistake is in the factory or in my controller

```
        **.factory('tasksFactory', function(){
          var tasks = [
                { info: "Finish with the sales report for July", date:Date("October 13 ,2014 11:13:00"), hoursplanned:140, hoursworked:166 },
                { info: "Finish with the sales report for July", date:Date("October 13 ,2014 11:13:00"), hoursplanned:140, hoursworked:166 },
                { info: "Finish with the sales report for July", date:Date("October 13 ,2014 11:13:00"), hoursplanned:140, hoursworked:166 },
                { info: "Finish with the sales report for July", date:Date("October 13 ,2014 11:13:00"), hoursplanned:140, hoursworked:166 },
                { info: "Finish with the sales report for July", date:Date("October 13 ,2014 11:13:00"), hoursplanned:140, hoursworked:166 },
            ];
            return tasks;
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are setting $scope.tasks to tasks, but tasks is only a variable within the scope of the factory. In your original post, the fastest answer would just be:

```
$scope.tasks = tasksFactory;
```

...however, I highly recommend you use a "getter" pattern as it is more standard.

My suggestion is to try this:

**Controller:**

```
.controller("TasksCtrl", function ($scope, tasksFactory) {

            $scope.tasks = tasksFactory.getTasks();

            $scope.addNew = function(task){
              alert("Add new called!");
              $scope.tasks.push(task);
            };

            $scope.remove = function(index){

              $scope.tasks.splice(index, 1);
            };
            $scope.edit= function(task){
              $scope.current = task;
            };
            $scope.save= function(task){
              $scope.current = {};
            };

})
```

**Factory**

```
.factory('tasksFactory', function(){
          var tasks = [
                { info: "Finish with the sales report for July", date:Date("October 13 ,2014 11:13:00"), hoursplanned:140, hoursworked:166 },
                { info: "Finish with the sales report for July", date:Date("October 13 ,2014 11:13:00"), hoursplanned:140, hoursworked:166 },
                { info: "Finish with the sales report for July", date:Date("October 13 ,2014 11:13:00"), hoursplanned:140, hoursworked:166 },
                { info: "Finish with the sales report for July", date:Date("October 13 ,2014 11:13:00"), hoursplanned:140, hoursworked:166 },
                { info: "Finish with the sales report for July", date:Date("October 13 ,2014 11:13:00"), hoursplanned:140, hoursworked:166 },
            ];

    function getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TasksFactory` returns an array.  If you really want to use it, try this little experiment - instead of `tasksFactory` call the factory `tasks`. Let me know what happens.